running simple tensorflow saved model in c (Segmentation fault)
I am able to run a simple "python tensorflow saved_model" with a input_tensor(-1,1) in c. But when I change my model to an model with input_tensor(-1,2), I get a Segmentation fault.
used versions

gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
tensorflow 2.15.0 (both python and c-lib)

This is how I created a simple python model:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.rand(100, 2)
y = 2 * X + 1 + 0.1 * np.random.randn(100, 1)

# Define the model architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(2,))
])

# Compile and train the model
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)

tf.saved_model.save(model, 'simple_example')

I checked the model with the command line tool:
saved_model_cli show --dir simple_example --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default

The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['dense_input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 2)
      name: serving_default_dense_input:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['dense'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

The c-code to run the model is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_Graph*  graph  = TF_NewGraph();
  TF_Buffer* r_opts = TF_NewBufferFromString("",0);
  TF_Buffer* meta_g = TF_NewBuffer();
  
  const char* dir_name = "..\\data\\simple_example";
  const char* InputOperationName = "serving_default_dense_input";
  int64_t in_dims[] = {2,1};
  int64_t out_dims[] = {1,1};
  
  //load the model
  TF_SessionOptions* opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  const char* tags[] = {"serve"};
  TF_Session* session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(opts, r_opts, dir_name, tags, 1, graph, meta_g, status);
  if (session == NULL || TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK )
    return -1;
  
  TF_Output input_op = {TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, InputOperationName ), 0};
  if (input_op.oper == NULL)
    return -1;

  // Define the input tensor
  TF_Tensor* input_tensor = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, in_dims, 2, in_dims[0] * in_dims[1] * sizeof(float));
  float* input_values = (float*)TF_TensorData(input_tensor);
  for (int n=0;n<(in_dims[0] * in_dims[1]);n++)
    input_values[n] = n;

  // Define the output tensor
  TF_Output output_op = {TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "StatefulPartitionedCall"), 0};
  if (output_op.oper == NULL)
    return -1;
  TF_Tensor* output_tensor = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, out_dims, 2, out_dims[0] * out_dims[1] * sizeof(float));
  
  // Run the session
  TF_SessionRun(session, NULL, &input_op, &input_tensor, in_dims[0]*in_dims[1], &output_op, &output_tensor, out_dims[0]*out_dims[1], NULL, 0, NULL, status);
  if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK)
  {
      printf("failed: %s\n", TF_Message(status));
      return -1;
  }
  
  float* output_values = (float*)TF_TensorData(output_tensor);
  printf("Output value: %d\n", output_values[0]);
  
  return 0;
}

my gdb output:
2024-06-21 14:10:16.608082: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:217] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: ..\data\simple_example
2024-06-21 14:10:17.113501: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:316] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 3129450 microseconds.

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff980b2c346 in tensorflow!?CopyFromInternal@Tensor@tensorflow@@AEAAXAEBV12@AEBVTensorShape@2@@Z ()
   from tensorflow\tensorflow.dll


Some of those library headers are not C, and the code contains C++.

sorry! I will correct my question

Are you still using g++?

@WeatherVane thanks for your second comment. I actually use gcc.
I have been struggling with this problem for many days. For tests I changed between gcc and g++ (and back). But did not check my question enough.

Did you check the values of the inputs from the python code. Such as for the value that works do you get the same output? What is the output when you run the broken values through?

So your create two different models, the one with an input shape of -1, 1 works. The one with an input shape of -1, 2 is broken? I thought you meant it breaks when you change the input values.

int64_t in_dims[] = {2,1}; shouldn't this be {1, 2} as batch size then input dimension size?

@matt thanks for your time. Indeed "So your create two different models, the one with an input shape of -1, 1 works. The one with an input shape of -1, 2 is broken?".
I tried your suggestion "{1, 2}"  before posting. But this does not help.

I found the tensorflow-lite, which suites my needs. I am using the lite-version with success. link.

I fixed the code so it works on linux but it had the same error as you get on windows.
You had two errors. The first error, the number of inputs.
TF_SessionRun(session, NULL, &input, &input_tensor, 1, &output, &output_tensor, 1, NULL, 0, NULL, status);

You have 2 and that was causing the segmentation fault.
The second error I mentioned in the comments, your input dimensions were backwards.

failed: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [2,1], In[1]: [2,1]
[[{{function_node __inference__wrapped_model_2222}}{{node sequential/dense/BiasAdd}}]]

That is fixed by creating the input dimensions correctly. int64_t in_dims[] = {1,2};
I compiled the example using:
 gcc -Iinclude -Llib sample.c -ltensorflow

Where include and lib are the folders from the tensorflow library.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_Graph*  graph  = TF_NewGraph();
  TF_Buffer* r_opts = TF_NewBufferFromString("",0);
  TF_Buffer* meta_g = TF_NewBuffer();
  
  const char* dir_name = "simple_example";
  const char* InputOperationName = "serving_default_dense_input";
  int64_t in_dims[] = {1,2};
  int64_t out_dims[] = {1,1};
  
  //load the model
  TF_SessionOptions* opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  const char* tags[] = {"serve"};
  TF_Session* session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(opts, r_opts, dir_name, tags, 1, graph, meta_g, status);
  if (session == NULL || TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK ){
    printf("couldn't start a session\n");
    return -1;
  }  
  TF_Operation* input_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, InputOperationName );
  TF_Output input = {input_op, 0};

  if (input.oper == NULL){
    printf("couldn't load input\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Define the output tensor
  TF_Operation* output_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "StatefulPartitionedCall");
  TF_Output output = {output_op, 0};
  
  if (output.oper == NULL){
    printf("couldn't load op\n");
    return -1;
  }
    // Define the input tensor
  TF_Tensor* input_tensor = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, in_dims, 2, in_dims[0] * in_dims[1] * TF_DataTypeSize(TF_FLOAT));
  
  float* input_values = (float*)TF_TensorData(input_tensor);
  for (int n=0;n<(in_dims[0] * in_dims[1]);n++)
    input_values[n] = n;

  TF_Tensor* output_tensor = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, out_dims, 2, out_dims[0] * out_dims[1] * TF_DataTypeSize(TF_FLOAT));
  
  // Run the session
  TF_SessionRun(session, NULL, &input, &input_tensor, 1, &output, &output_tensor, 1, NULL, 0, NULL, status);
  if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK)
  {
      printf("failed: %s\n", TF_Message(status));
      return -1;
  }
  printf("ran the code!\n");
  float* output_values = (float*)TF_TensorData(output_tensor);
  printf("Output value: %f\n", output_values[0]);
  
  return 0;
}


Thank you for taking the time to solve my problem! You are right I made two mistakes. Because of the wrong size specified at TF_SessionRun my change trail-and-error at the in_dims did not help me. Now the code is running.

You can debug a segmentation fault by compiling with debug-symbols (e.g. gcc -g) and then running the binary in gdb.
E.g.:
$ gcc -g model.c
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) run
[SEGFAULT occurs]
(gdb) backtrace
[calltrace shown]

Valgrind and clang/gcc sanitizers are also a great tool for debugging such issues.

thanks for your reply. Because I did not have success with the sensorflow library I switch to the tensorflow-lite library to run my model.
By cleaning up my code, I lost the code above....
